# Opening very large TIF image sequences

Tags: python, c++, image, tiff, large-files

I have a set (>10,000) of large uncompressed images (1200,1600) stored as a TIFF stack.

I cannot load these directly into memory as the total size of the file exceeds the available memory. Is there a mechanism, in either python (preferable) or C++ (passable) whereby the stack can be opened frame by frame (or in blocks) to remove the need to load the whole stack into memory.

I have tried the `tifffile` and `PIL` packages in python which only read in the first frame, presumably as both have safeguards to prevent loading in images larger than the available memory.

eg.

```
from PIL import Image

V = Image.open(filepath)

print(V.size)
```

above returns `(1200,1600)` which is not 3D as it should be

```
from tifffile import TiffFile

V = TiffFile(filepath)

print(len(V.pages))
```

returns `1` which should be >10,000

It may not be possible to parse through the frames without loading the whole stack, but I am looking for potential options

Comment: Well, you could memory-map the file.

Comment: Memory-mapping a TIFF file seems pointless, as the data would be stored in a complex manner, you'd have to reimplement the TIFF standard and copy the relevant data over to a contiguous buffer, better to use existing libraries for  that. And depending on virtual memory seems a particularly poor suggestion, obvious to anyone who has been waiting on a thrashing program.

Comment: Does `V.seek(1)` etc... to step through the frames work?

Comment: FYI -- Since you tagged C++, and I do not know Python's libraries, [libtiff](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/) is the library that most C++ apps use for TIFF reading/writing.  Almost all free and open source C++ programs that have anything to do with TIFF files use libtiff.

Comment: @cgohlke These were produced in [imagej](https://imagej.net/software/fiji/), the metadata output is `SizeX 1600, SizeY 1200, SizeZ 5000,  PixelType uint16`

Comment: Use tifffile to memory-map the image data in the ImageJ hyperstack to a numpy array: `stack = tifffile.memmap('stack.tif')`. Usual TIFF reader like PIL and libtiff will not be able to access the whole stack.

Comment: This approach works as expected the resulting `stack` object has a shape `(5000, 1200, 1600)` and can be maniupulated as expected for a 3D numpy array

Answer (score 1):

You said you tried the `tifffile` package. The [documentation](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) shows you can read individual pages, a subset of pages, or even iterate over the pages:

> Read the image from the first page in the TIFF file as NumPy array:
>
> ```
> >>> image = imread('temp.tif', key=0)
> >>> image.shape
> (301, 219)
> ```
>
> Read images from a selected range of pages:
>
> ```py
> >>> images = imread('temp.tif', key=range(4, 40, 2))
> >>> images.shape
> (18, 301, 219)
> ```
>
> Iterate over all pages in the TIFF file and successively read images:
>
> ```
> >>> with TiffFile('temp.tif') as tif:
> ...     for page in tif.pages:
> ...         image = page.asarray()
> ```

I am sure Pillow (née PIL) has a similar possibility.

I would recommend [Bio-Formats](https://www.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/) ([python-bioformats](https://github.com/CellProfiler/python-bioformats)) for working specialized file types, and [imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for ordinary file types. Your TIFF files seem to be somewhere in between, either would help you with them.

Comment: The `tifffile` approach also gives a 2D array and not the expected 3D so the `key=` approach fails eg. `from tifffile import imread

V = imread('file')

V.shape` yields `(1200,1600)`

Comment: @j1ling67n As you said, you have a set of images of size 1200x1600. Those are 2D images. They should be stacked to form a 3D image. You cannot read them all in at once because it'd be too large. So you can read a subset of them, process the partial 3D image, discard, read the next subset, etc. `tiffile` gives you that option, as do the two other more generic packages I linked.